Is the trinity biblically backed
I'm wondering where the doctrine of the trinity comes from, and I've only found that it stems from both Hellenistic philosophy (Platonism through Philo and Origen) and Babylonian polytheism (Nimrod, Semiramis, and Tammuz). It doesn't make sense for a triune god to be monotheistic. Has anyone else ever questioned its origins and come to a different understanding? Please let me know.
I am specifically looking for instances of it in the Tanakh.
(I am not looking for verses that have scribal errors)

See also: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/12628/what-is-the-origin-of-the-doctrine-of-trinity

Well yes it does; But it is hard to accept such an answer if your faith belongs to Judaism. It is a little complicated.
In Orthodox Christianity we say that Jesus Christ was Crucified to take the burden of our sins and save us from death, meaning a mental death, death of the soul. How does the soul dies? Sins kill you. So we live in a new era, without the burden of sins, we should not follow the law of GOD, nobody can follow the law anyway, salvation is not hidden there; Instead in the New Testament, Jesus Christ gave us a new law. And that new law was "Love each other as much as you love yourself".
Now Judaism has ten commands and one of them is Thou shalt not make unto thee any graven image. Judaism believes that worshiping Jesus Christ as the Son of God breaks that rule.
But there are references about Jesus Christ in the Biblie:
Isaiah 52:13-53:12. 
Isaiah 7:14. ...
Isaiah 9:6-7. ...
Genesis 3:15. ...
Genesis 12:1-3. ...
Deuteronomy 18:15-18. ...
2 Samuel 7:12-13. ...
Micah 5:2.

Most important though, Orthodox Christianity goes farther than that. An Archbishop theologist told me that  when an Angel of God appears in Tanakh, it is not actually an angel, but Jesus himself, with no human form yet. It is believed that the Son was forever along with the Father and the Holy Spirit.By the way Tanakh and the orthodox Old Testament have differences anyway.
Yet God is ONE and Triune. It makes perfect sense.
The same way as the Gospel is one with four forms (points of view). Does that make sense? If yes why not Triune God?
Speaking of reason though, trying to make sense while studying religion may make your head spin.
For instance, God split the water and God's people passed...
Does that make ANY sense? Manna was raining from the sky so people found food and survived. Does that make ANY sense? Does it HAVE to? Religion is about FAITH, not logic.
Edit:
Gospel of John. First sentence.
"In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God."
Word is Jesus Christ. To be exact the word used in Greek was "Λόγος".
Λόγος means more than Word though.
It means logic, speech, reason but Λόγος was used to refer to Jesus Christ.
I am not a theologian myself to analyze it, I just do my own research and I do my  best here helping you out.

This answer supports binitarianism, not the trinity. To "back" the Trinity Doctrine, one must prove that God's holy spirit is a self-aware entity.

@RayButterworth Binitarian ? the Son was forever along with the Father and the Holy Spirit. .

@NigelJ, simply stating "It is believed that …" is not the same as providing biblical backing.

@RayButterworth You say the answer supports binitarinism. I am still looking for evidence. What the answer does state is "the Son was forever along with the Father and the Holy Spirit.".

@NigelJ, I didn't say the answer is evidence or proof that Jesus is God. I'm saying that the biblical references it does provide are all with respect to Jesus, and that it does not provide any support for the third person.

Sigh... Gospel of John. I will edit my answer...

@RayButterworth not really. Holy Spirit, Son and God are one and the same in Orthodoxy. I mean, we say God is one. Ένας και Τριαδικος. Same goes for the Gospel. We say it is one but with four forms. Ένα και τετράμορφο. What makes you think I support binitarianism? To support the Holy Spirit existence You begin with Jesus Christ. It is hard to explain, it is considered one the three hypostases. Not three natures, three hypostases, I remember now. So Since Jesus is the Word of God, since He is the God, thus he also is the Holy Spirit. Holy spirit is not a person. It's a hypostasis.

@GeorgeEco, the question is about what the Bible says, not what various denominations already believe. The quotations you gave support the idea that Christ is God, but they don't support the idea that holy spirit is God. (They don't deny it either; I'm just pointing out that they don't support a third member.)

Okay, so Jesus refers to the Holy Spirit as it is a person in John's Gospel if that helps.
Also there is a Mathew reference
Go therefore and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit
From Corinthians:
So then, about eating food sacrificed to idols: We know that “An idol is nothing at all in the world” and that “There is no God but one.
